# sorting a csv file alphabetically Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I want to convert a CSV file into an array and then sort the array alphabetically

```
Wagner
Knox
Brennan
Shaw
Morin
Phelps
Mccoy
Hays
Burgess
Bowman
```

This is the CSV file that I have and I need to sort it alphabetically.

This is what I have so far:

```
Dim location As String = "C:\Users\6\Desktop"
        Dim file As String = "names.csv"
        Dim sr As New StreamReader(file & location)
        System.Array.Sort(sr)
Console.WriteLine(sr)
```

It doesn't work because `sr` is not a string so it won't sort.

What could I do to make the code work?

Comment: `Dim arr = Array.Sort(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(System.IO.Path.Combine(Location, file)))`

Comment: Read string and split into array and so on.

Comment: And that if you have a name per line. Also you can try: `Dim arr = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(System.IO.Path.Combine(Location, file)).OrderBy(Function(x) x).ToArray`

Comment: @JQSOFT please post answers in answers, not in comments

Comment: @CaiusJard Sure, next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mostly there, but it will be easier to read all the lines in the file into an array using File.ReadAllLines (need to import System.IO) rather than using a streamreader. ReadALlLines will nicely read the file, split it up into an array of one line per array element, close the file, clean up after itself etc

```
    Dim location As String = "C:\Users\6\Desktop"
    Dim file As String = "names.csv"
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(location, file))
    System.Array.Sort(lines)

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines))
```

Always use `Path.Combine()` to build paths, NOT the `&` operator